# Web mode in Intellij 10 using gwt 2.1

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ Idea using GWT 1.4 there used to be a way to use various browsers in what they called web mode to ensure that the application worked in all of them before deployment.  Has that gone away?  Now a plugin is needed for hosted mode and there isn't one for Opera.  So, I deploy the application and then see that it doesn't display right in Opera.  At the moment I then make a change and redeploy the application to test.  Obviously that is a slow process. Is there any way to test locally without plugins and without my having to install a server locally?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such way. Since Opera isn't supported in GWT Dev Mode the only way to test the application in it is running in Production Mode. Note that Web Mode in GWT 1.4 also called GWT compiler so it wasn't faster.

Comment: I think I am going to have to add some Javascript on the main page to test for Opera, and tell the user to use a different browser.  I've used Opera for many years (since 1.x days) but I think the time has finally come to move on. Testing using the GWT compiler was a lot faster than having to copy all the files up to the web server and then testing.  Also there is no way to debug through the code in Opera.  There are too many other browsers that have a plugin available for me to fight issues with Opera.